# Regex to add spaces around '=' in C++ code, what have I done wrong?

Tags: c++, regex

I would like to create a regex which will allow me to add spaces around assignment operators in C++ code (as I prefer this style), e.g. so that

```
x=something
```

becomes

```
x = something
```

but

```
if(y==x)
```

does not become

```
if(y = = x)
```

and so on including `!=`,`<=`,`>=`

I am relatively new to regular expressions and have tried the following:

```
(?<![\s=])(=)(?!=)
```

I thought this would be a good starter, but this does not seem to match. Could someone explain what I have not understood about regex here?

**Edit**

Example using regex which does not match in Code::Blocks IDE

[image: Code::BLocks regex attempt]

Comment: You want to replace each `=` with one preceded and succeeded by whitespace, right? Or is it to allow optional spaces before and after each `=`?

Comment: Test your regex out here: http://regex101.com/r/xA4pN7 (automatic explanation for it, too)

Comment: @NaveedS, yep, one space before and after the `=`if there are no spaces already.

Comment: Not the most elegant solution, but what I'd do is simply put spaces around all `=`, and then replace things like `= *=` with `==`.

Comment: Also: just how correct does it have to be?  Distinguishing between `*p++=a` (to `*p++ = a`) and `*p+=a` (to `*p += a`) would almost require a full C++ lexer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this: `(?<![<>=!])\s*=\s*(?!=)` replaced with `=`.

OR

`([^<>=!])\s*=\s*([^=])` replaced with `\1 = \2`

Both lookaround assertions are needed since the pattern is not anchored.

Your own regex was, in reality, just missing `<>` in the character class. I have improved on it a tiny bit, look at the demo.

Demo+explanation for first regex: http://regex101.com/r/kU1hP2
Demo+explanation for second regex: http://regex101.com/r/lK1oQ3

Note: `\s` matches whitespace!

Comment: Your answer works at the link you supplied, but does not work [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html), or in my editor (Code::Blocks). Any idea why?

Comment: @crobar: What did you insert into the search box? Can you take a print screen? It could be that it does not support negative lookbehinds, or lookarounds at all.

Comment: I've added a screen grab of Code::Blocks with the regex (you can see some things which should match in the bg. But as I said, it also doesn't seem to match at [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html). I'm pretty sure it will support both positive and negative lookaround.

Comment: Very odd. Does it not support negative lookarounds? I figured it did from your initial expression. Added an alternative expression without lookarounds you can try.

Comment: The new expression works on the other website, but not in the editor. Maybe it does not support lookaround at all. Possibly I just need to use a different editor to do this. I'll mark your (double) answer correct.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't cover everything.

If you want spaces you need to consider a little more.

Try this
http://regex101.com/r/oJ8jJ3

```
((!|<|>|=|\+|%)=|=)
```

And use the \1 separator

In some styles of regex, that may look like this:

```
s/((!|<|>|=|\+|%)=|=)/ \1 /g
```

Good luck!
P.S.
Cases considered:

```
x=something
if(y==x)
if(y <=x)
if(y>=x)
y+=x;
y%=x;
```

Comment: Also ((!|<|>|=|\+|%)=|==|===) if you are considering other languages with the triple equals operator.